# Access Windows 7 network printer queues from Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, networking, printing

**Background:**  The recent Microsoft Update KB5006670 has left one of my customers Windows 10 workstation without working print queues to a  proprietary print controller (CREO IC-304).  Enabling SMB1 and uninstalling the HotFix allows us to re-install the queues via Point and Print.  But this is obviously a temporary fix until MS enforces their patch which they should and will to cope with PrintNightmare.

My customer must use Windows 10 to support publishing software requirements but needs those applications to print natively to network print queues that - very soon - will only be sustainable on Windows 7.

**Problem:** Windows 7 can't seem to share the network printer queues.

They are configured shared:

[image]

Network discovery and File and Printer sharing are both enabled:
[image]

But the printers still cannot be seen on the network:

[image]

**Further investigation shows other (more modern) network printers CAN be shared so this must be a deficiency in the IC-304 print driver and/or print processor that prevents Windows 7 from sharing them.**

[image]

**No solution: the printer drivers involved are simply too archaic to be in service any more.**

Answer (score 0):

Relying on Windows 7 is (as you note) not a good idea.

Put the Printer directly on the user's Network and configure it for network access. This will work for Windows 10 (I do this) without relying on Windows 7 or any other computer.

Make sure Windows 10 is fully up to date as Windows print issues were fixed earlier this year.

Most printers now have an Ethernet port and so use that.

If not, get a small Print Server device that connects the printer to the network.

Eliminating Print Sharing is the best thing to do.

If none of the above can work (old printer) then get a Print Output on the Windows 7 machine and then move that by whatever means available to Windows 10.

Comment: I'm sorry John.  None of these suggestions are helpful.    In case I did not make it quite plain: replacing the print server is not an option.  It is proprietary, unalterable, and required for my customers business.  Likewise the ONLY operating systems capable of running required printer drivers and print processor are XP, Vista, and Windows 7 - I think you will agree that choice is pretty obvious.  Please re-read the question asked - I would appreciate any insight you have within that context.

Comment: Are you saying the printer has no Windows 10 Driver?  That would make it a very old printer because Windows 10 has many, many Printer drivers. That is why I think a Print Server would work. If truly no Windows 10 fit, you might consider a newer printer.

Comment: Positively ancient drivers, I'm afraid.  circa 2004.  The printer in question is commercial printing/copying equipment and tightly integrated with the print server - they are for all practical purposes a unit and far too expensive to replace them both - customer would have to close up shop.

Comment: That is very old - too old for Windows 10. Try printing to a file or like method on Windows 7 and then have Windows 10 get the output from Windows 7. There is not much alternative.

Comment: Sneaker-Net is the last option.  But the RDP solution is still viable.  And I haven't used all the tricks in my bag.  I might yet get those queues shared from the Windows 7 vm.

Comment: RDP might work. In any event, I amended my answer to include old printer output possibilities .

Comment: RDP does work.  As I said in the last paragraph, the print queues installed on Window 7 are redirected and fully functional in a session to the Windows 10 OS.  I just don't want the user to have interactive access to the Windows 7 system.